# Manipulating the DateTime object in Google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, datetime

I am making a blog and store the publishing date of a blog post in the datastore. It looks like this:

```
post.date = datetime.datetime.now()
```

It now displays like: 2010-10-04 07:30:15.204352 But I want the datetime to be displayed differently. How (and where) can I set that how the date is displayed? I'd like to set the date format like in UNIX date function (like %Y/%m etc). I tried to add some parameters in my templates but that returned errors.

Thanks in advance!

-skazhy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think [strftime](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime) is the method you're looking for.

From the link:

```
>>> d.strftime("%d/%m/%y")
'11/03/02'
```

If you pass in the result of the `strftime` in your 'template_values' or similar (the dictionary you use to pass parameters to the template) instead of the actual date it will be displayed instead.

Comment: Yes.  Just note that the python 2.7 GAE environment does not support the strftime format string: %s (UNIX epoch timestamp), which does work on native Python 2.7 installations (e.g. the GAE dev server environment!). This bit me today :-/  Have phun.

Answer (score 2):

You can use .strftime() on a datetime object to do the formatting. See the [relevant python documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime) for details.